# How do I include a model connected to only one item in the array?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a route that is pulling from multiple models that belong to eachother.
Production > Showing > Seat, Ticket > X (where Ticket hasMany X).

How do I set up my route to get the info X as an object under ticket?

Here is my currently working code without the 'include' for X

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const productionData = await Production.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: Showing,
        include: [Seat, Ticket]
      }]
    })
    console.log("Production Daeta", productionData)
    res.status(200).json(productionData)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }  
});
```

Comment: Did you try to include `X`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any further knowledge of your question you should the nestings as deep as necessary.

```
 const productionData = await Production.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Showing,
      include: [
        { model: Seat },
        {
          model: Ticket,
          include: [
            {
              model: X,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

This way all nestings will be returned.
A minor notice is that this will be a rather heavy query and it might be usefull to add

> seperate: true

at a certain point when you have many joins in a query.